# How to override onclick of notification

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, parse-platform

I am using parse.com to send push notification to my application.

I am receiving the notification and it shows fine.

I want a dialog box to show when I receive the notification with some data displayed and then on user selecting positive response to open an activity from my app.

The problem i am facing is that when the screen is unlocked and on, the dialog shows. But if the screen is locked it does not. and on clicking the notification it opens my launcher activity on its own.

Is there anyway to override the onclick event of the notification in the notification of the tray?

I used this example as a reference.

https://github.com/ahiraz/pushNotificationDemo

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";
    GPSTracker gps;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            if (intent == null)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Receiver intent null");
            }
            else
            {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action );




                if (action.equals("com.epcon.helpmebangalore.activities.UPDATE_STATUS"))
                {
                    String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

                    Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");

                            Intent pupInt = new Intent(context, ShowPopUp.class);
                            pupInt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );

                            context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(pupInt);

                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context,YourActivityClassHere.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    //UNIQUE_ID if you expect more than one notification to appear
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(SimpleNotification.this, UNIQUE_ID, 
                notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Dont i need to do startActivity(intent) anywhere?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the code. please specify what i should do accordingly